# mysql запрос без обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

ХЕЕЕЕЛП! Есть html форма и файл в котором происходит запрос к бд по нажатию на кнопку. Как можно сделать, чтобы запрос происходил без перезагрузки страницы

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<input id="street" name="street" type="text" required="" placeholder="Название улицы" autocomplete="off" class="suggestions-input" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
<input id="house" name="house" type="text" required="" placeholder="Номер дома" autocomplete="off" class="suggestions-input" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Проверить">
</form>

<?php
$host = '*******'; 
  $user = '*******';   
  $pass = '*****';
  $db_name = '******';   
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); 

  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
 if(isset($_POST['smb']))
{
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
$a=0;
$street= $_POST['street'];
$house = $_POST['house'];
 $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM test');
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
if (($result['street']==$street)&&($result['house']==$house)){
    $a=$a+1;}
  }
if ($a>0) {echo "Подключение возможно.";} else {echo "Подключение невозможно.";} 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Получите значение элемента формы через document.getElementById('i_input').value и отправьте форму через AJAX запрос. Пример запроса:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'response.php?action=sample2',
      data: 'name=Andrew&nickname=Aramis',
      success: function(data){
        $('.results').html(data);
      }
});
```